# Regarding excel service in sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, excel-services

We planning to purchase Sharepoint 2010 standard version. I notice SharePoint 2010 standard version does not support Excel service.

My question is, am still able to load the excel document in document library?. Open and download and save?

Please advise

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can upload, open, download/save your Excel docs to a document library with any edition of SharePoint 2010.